# Como crear una instancia nueva de un objeto en un arreglo de javascript y modificar sus variables sin modificar el objeto del primero

Tags: javascript

El problema es el siguiente tengo un arreglo global con una lista de objetos y quiero hacer modificaciones temporales a un elemento de la lista y quiero que las modificaciones en el elemento sean temporales, es decir si vuelvo a acceder a ese elemento de la lista debe estar como lo deje al principio.

Estos son los intentos que he hecho

Intento 1 :

```
var objetos1 = [{nombre : 'israel'}];
var objeto = new Object( objetos1[0] );
var objetos2 = [objeto];
objetos2[0].nombre = 'enrique';
console.debug(objetos1[0].nombre);//Espero que diga israel
console.debug(objetos2[0].nombre);//Espero que diga enrique
```

Intento 2 :

```
var objetos1 = [{nombre : 'israel'}];
var objetos2 = new Array();
objetos2.push( new Object( objetos1[0] ) )
objetos2[0].nombre = 'enrique';
console.debug(objetos1[0].nombre);//Espero que diga israel
console.debug(objetos2[0].nombre);//Espero que diga enrique
```

En los 2 intentos el resultado es el mismo, si modifico el objeto del primer o el segundo arreglo se modificaran en los 2, por lo tanto siempre dira `enrique`.

Estoy tratando de evitar tener que hacer una asignacion de todas las propiedades a un nueva variable ya que cuando son pocas propiedades el código es pequeño y funciona pero al ser muchas propiedades tendría que crear una función que haga el mapeo y no es la opción que quiero.

Es posible perder la referencia al objeto con una función que cree una copia del mismo, la cual hice generica, pero espero encontrar una mejor solución.

```
/**
 * Copia las propiedades principales
 * de un objeto a otro.
 * @param objetoOriginal Objeto original con las propiedaes a copiar.
 * @param objetoCopia Objeto al que se le copiaran las propiedades.
 * @return objeto copia con las propiedades del objeto original.
 * @author Jesus Perales.
 */
function copiarValoresObjeto(objetoOriginal, objetoCopia){
    for (var prop in objetoOriginal) {
        if (objetoOriginal.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            objetoCopia[prop] = objetoOriginal[prop];
        }
    }
    return objetoCopia;
}
```

Comment: Tienes que crear un nuevo objecto y pasarle manualmente los valores!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria convertirlo a JSON de la siguiente forma....

```
var objectos2 = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( objetos1 ) ); 
objectos2[ 'nombre' ] = "enrique"; 
console.log( objectos1[ 'name' ] ); // israel
console.log( objectos2[ 'name' ] ); // enrique
```

http://www.etnassoft.com/2013/10/15/copiando-arrays-y-objetos-en-javascript/

Comment: Solo por favor deja la fuente principal

http://www.etnassoft.com/2013/10/15/copiando-arrays-y-objetos-en-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`Object#create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/create) :

```js
var o = {nombre : 'israel'};
var o2 = Object.create(o);

o2.nombre = 'Perico';
console.log(o, o2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Han pasado 2 años!, espero que esto ayude...

```js
    var objetos = {nombre : 'israel'};
    var a = Object.create(objetos);
    var b = Object.create(objetos);
    var objetos1 = [];
    var objetos2 = [];
    objetos1.push(a);
    objetos2.push(b);
    objetos2[0].nombre = 'enrique';
    console.log(objetos1[0].nombre);//israel
    console.log(objetos2[0].nombre);//enrique
```

Comment: Hola Alberto, bienvenido al sitio. Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir algo de detalle explicando qué hace el código y cómo resuelve el problema. Completa el [tour] y lee [answer] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).